# optimizing sql query with multiple select from

Tags: sql-server, select

Hi everyone I am hoping for some help/insight/ideas on how to best select data from my tables(I can do inner joins but that's about as "complicated" as my knowledge goes with SQL). Well I'm using this query but it takes 4 hours

```
SELECT   FROM 
(
 SELECT  FROM 
 (
SELECT    FROM        )AS 
 )
 AS ....
(SELECT     ...FROM         ...  )AS...,
(SELECT     .....FROM         ...   )
AS ...
(SELECT     ........FROM         ....)   AS ....
(SELECT....FROM         ....  )AS ...
(SELECT     ...FROM         ....  )AS ...,
(SELECT    .....FROM         .....   )AS [.....
( SELECT    .....FROM         .....   )AS [.....
(SELECT    .....FROM         .....   ) AS [.....
(SELECT    .....FROM         .....   )   AS [.....
(SELECT    .....FROM         .....   )   AS [.....
WHERE 
(
And (
And ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `JOIN`s tend to be faster than nested `SELECT`s so see if you can recast the query to use them.

An alternative approach is to have a look at the execution plan for your query, see which part takes longest and try and speed up that part. You'll hugely broaden your understanding of SQL in doing this, so even if it only takes the execution time down to 3h 55m you will gain a lot from it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. At the EP "clustred index scan" takes longest